# Joomla! working Dropdown menu on Touch device or, Non-clickable menu header with published content

Tags: menu

I am making a Joomla! site with 3 level 1 menus that break down into multiple submenus.
The site works wonderfully on Desktop as the sub-menus appear on hover.

On touch devices though, i am not able to make the dropdowns appear as i cannot simulate the hover event. When i tap on the level 1 items, the browser follows the links instead of opening the dropdown items.

I am looking for a way to make them non-clickable on touch, or maybe 1st tap should open the dropdown and second tap follow the link.

I have tried making the 1st level menus text separators or menu headings, which disables them in desktop too and works ok.
I am ok with that but, in that case i need a way to add content to those paths, so that if someone manually enters the address gets some content.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: upon hover on the desktop version, does it add a class that the menu item such as `active` or `selected`?

Comment: Is this really a Joomla question. It's more about mobile web UX. Anyway IMHO trying to emulate a hover using a short/long press is bad design.

Comment: Any further detail about software used and version of Joomla?

Comment: Its 3.something but will come back to you asap on the versions. Is there any way i could leave the menus as text separators (so that they are non-clickable at all) and at the same time control the content that will be published at those urls in case some one enters them manually? (instead of giving a 404 error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up making the 3 top level menus normal menus, redirecting to articles etc.
Added a "unlink" class to those 3 top level menu items.

Then added a custom jquery to prevent the links from working:
`jQuery('.unlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    });`

This way, if someone manually enters the link to the address line there is content there to guide them through and at the same time menus are usable on mobile/touch devices.

Got the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link